# Azure .NET SDK not handling filters correctly (ConsumptionClient)?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core-2.0, azure-sdk-.net

I'm calling the Azure Usage API trying to use a filter to get machine specific information.

The return values are valid, but it seems like either the REST API or the C# library is sending the request incorrectly.

This is the code:

```
var filterString = $"instanceName eq '{vm.VirtualMachineName}'";

vmConsumptionData = await consumptionClient.Item1.UsageDetails.ListAsync(
                    scope: $"/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}",
                    filter: filterString 
                );
```

According to the log, my request is being sent with the following:

> https://management.azure.com//subscriptions/{SubscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.Consumption/usageDetails?$filter=instanceName%20eq%20%27{correct instance name}%27&api-version=2017-11-30

However, this is always returning the same 24 results, even when submitting a different instance name.

I have tried removing certain parts of the filter 'query' and it always returns the same 24 results (which are not virtual machine resource types).

Am I calling the library incorrectly? Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.consumption.usagedetailsoperationsextensions.listasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_Consumption_UsageDetailsOperationsExtensions_ListAsync_Microsoft_Azure_Management_Consumption_IUsageDetailsOperations_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Nullable_System_Int32__System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the SDK differs in the filtering and is somewhat clear from the documentation. You should call with the following:

> properties/usageEnd (Utc time) 
>   properties/usageStart (Utc time)
>   properties/resourceGroup
>   properties/instanceName
>   properties/instanceId

Changing my `filterString` to:

```
var filterString = $"properties/instanceName  eq \'{vm.VirtualMachineName}\'";
```

Did the job.

Comment: I was struggling with date ranges and that page helped me: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/consumption/  - in general you must pass both start and end date in order to make date filter work!